# Accessible dropdown menu: <li> has multiple children

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wcag

I'm working on making a dropdown menu accessible. I'm largely following this W3 example: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/menubar/menubar-1/menubar-1.html#

However, my menu has an unusual structure. Some of my list item's contain more than one button, which are horizontally aligned within the list item.

```html
<ul role="menu">
 <li role="none">Header</li>
 <li role="none">
  <button role="menuitem">Option A</button>
  <button role="menuitem">Option B</button>
  <button role="menuitem">Option C</button></li>
 <li role="none">
  <button role="menuitem">Button Foo</button>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a recommended way to make this WCAG accessible? 
I'd like the user to use the LEFT/RIGHT keys to move between the buttons inside a list item.

Furthermore, currently my screenreader (NVDA) will inform the user that there are 4 items within the list (due to there being 4 elements with the role="menuitem" tag). Ideally I'd like the screenreader to let the user know that there are only 2 items in the list, and then when he is on a button with siblings (e.g. "Option A" in my example), I'd like the screenreader to announce that, besides being in the first item in the menu, it is option 1 out of 3 in the list item.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question at the moment is too broad. There are at least two seperate issues here. One: Using the LEFT/RIGHT keys to navigate the buttons, this is a javascript issue and you should show some attempt at solving the issue.  Two: the *wcag* requirements for the screen reader, and this could also probably be broken down into more than one question. Please keep you question to one issue. Ask multiple questions if needed.

Answer (score 1):

***IMPORTANT NOTE***: The `menu` role and pattern is designed to be used in applications. If you want to do a menu for a simple website, you should use the `navigation` role

---

Answering now, your question...

You are describing what [`menuitemradio`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#menuitemradio) role is intended for: (note: *this could also be `menutitemcheckbox` if different options are not exclusive*)

```
<ul role="menu">
    <li role="none" id="group_header">Header</li>
    <li role="group" aria-describedby="group_header">
        <button role="menuitemradio">Option A</button>
        <button role="menuitemradio">Option B</button>
        <button role="menuitemradio">Option C</button></li>
    <li role="none">
        <button role="menuitem">Button Foo</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> I'd like the user to use the LEFT/RIGHT keys to move between the buttons inside a list item.

You can see the requisits for keyboard interactions for `menu` role items [on the WAI ARIA Authoring practices](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#keyboard-interaction-12), which include more than just the left and right keys. So you will have to rely on important javascript development for your application.

---

**Note**: Remember, that if you are designing a website (so your menu won't be in an `application` role), you should use the `navigation` role. This would be easier and you could use any standard HTML elements like `input[type='radio']` which will natively handle the left and right key:

```
<ul role="navigation" aria-label="Menu">
   <li><div id="group_header">Header</div>
     <div role="group" aria-describedby="group_header">
        <label><input type="radio" name="item" /> Option A</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="item" /> Option B</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="item" /> Option C</label>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li><button>Button Foo</button></li>
</ul>
```

A discussion on the ["menu not for website" theme](https://github.com/w3c/aria-practices/issues/353)

Comment: I disagree with your suggestion to use menuitemradio. This role let assume that one of the items in the group is currently active while others are inactive, and that a single option may be active at a time.
It may not be what the asker wants. As far as I understand, A, B and C are just three possible actions. Using submenus may be more appropriate.

Comment: @QuentinC You're right. Op said that A, B and C where 3 **options** (not actions), but nothing says that they are exclusive as I have supposed. I added a short note about using `menuitemcheckbox` if necessary.